# Zookeeper - Where do I find the "real" version of a running instance of Zookeeper?

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I recently installed a new ZK node w/ Exhibitor, it started fine. When I do a `telnet localhost 2181` and then run a `stats` to see the version, even though I installed 3.4.11, I keep seeing 3.4.5 build in the output. I tried to find where does ZooKeeper read the version number but it's just a .jar and some lib files. Do you know where can I get the "real" version I'm supposed to be running? Thanks!

This is what I see when doing `telnet`:

```
myserver:/tmp/zookeeper # telnet localhost 2181
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
stats
Zookeeper version: 3.4.5-1392090, built on 09/30/2012 17:52 GMT
Clients:
 /127.0.0.1:53133[0](queued=0,recved=1,sent=0)

Latency min/avg/max: 0/0/0
Received: 41
Sent: 40
Connections: 1
Outstanding: 0
Zxid: 0x0
Mode: standalone
Node count: 4
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Running process (`ps aux | grep zookeeper`) shows:

```
myuser    19002  0.9  1.2 2618596 49596 ?       Sl   14:02   0:00 /usr/pkgs/java/1.8.0.92/bin/java -Dzookeeper.log.dir=/var/run/zookeeper/log -Dzookeeper.root.logger=WARN,ROLLINGFILE -cp /opt/zookeeper-server/default/bin/../build/classes:/opt/zookeeper-server/default/bin/../build/lib/*.jar:/opt/zookeeper-server/default/bin/../lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar:/opt/zookeeper-server/default/bin/../lib/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar:/opt/zookeeper-server/default/bin/../lib/netty-3.10.5.Final.jar:/opt/zookeeper-server/default/bin/../lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar:/opt/zookeeper-server/default/bin/../lib/jline-0.9.94.jar:/opt/zookeeper-server/default/bin/../lib/exhibitor-1.6.0.jar:/opt/zookeeper-server/default/bin/../lib/audience-annotations-0.5.0.jar:/opt/zookeeper-server/default/bin/../zookeeper-3.4.11.jar:/opt/zookeeper-server/default/bin/../src/java/lib/*.jar:/var/run/zookeeper/conf: -server -Xmx1g -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain /var/run/zookeeper/conf/zoo.cfg
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking source, it seems that there's an interface called Info who gives the version number. It can be seen here: https://github.com/apache/zookeeper/blob/master/src/java/main/org/apache/zookeeper/Version.java

So, version file is done at build time.

Answer (score 23):

ZooKeeper supports four letter commands, assuming you're running ZooKeeper on localhost:

```
$ echo "status" | nc  localhost 2181 | head -n 1
Zookeeper version: 3.4.9-3--1, built on Fri, 24 May 2019 08:57:53 +0100
```

using some bash magic, you can filter out the main version:

```
$ echo "status" | nc  localhost 2181 | head -n 1 | awk '{ print $3}' | cut -d "-" -f 1
```

Answer (score 4):

cat zookeeper-server.log | grep zookeeper.version

....
INFO Server environment:zookeeper.version=**3.5.7**-f0fdd52973d373ffd9c86b81d99842dc2c7f660e, built on 02/10/2020 11:30 GMT (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
.....

Answer (score 3):

The AdminServer
New in 3.5.0: The AdminServer is an embedded Jetty server that provides an HTTP interface to the four letter word commands. By default, the server is started on port 8080, and commands are issued by going to the URL "/commands/[command name]", e.g., http://localhost:8080/commands/stat
Example:

```
$  curl -s http://localhost:8080/commands/envi |grep zookeeper.version  
$ "zookeeper.version" : "3.5.8"
```